# Problem with CHQ1838 schematic

Tags: arduino, infrared, schematic

[image]Hello, I have problem with this schematic, the Arduino did not receive any signal.
What is wrong with it?

I have this schematic provided by producer
[image]

Comment: How did you implement it?

Comment: By the schematic provided

Comment: I have this on my pcb

Comment: @MateuszBielak - Hi, You said you got [that 2nd schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQ3rq.jpg) from the producer (I guess that's the supplier). Was that from a website? If so, please [edit] the question to add their name and the link to the source webpage / PDF etc. as required by the [site rule on referencing](/help/referencing). TY

Answer (score 1):

The schematic from the manufacturer shows a pull-up resistor on the output. You have connected the output and the 5V lines together so the output can never be pulled down. You may have also destroyed the internal pull-down transistor.

Comment: How can I change it to make it work?

Comment: @MateuszBielak actually copy the schematic from the vendor. It is fundamentally different than yours!